# web site, webservice, web API

Tags: web-services, api-design, webapi

I am new here and confused by few things

- Some web sites (twitter, foursquare, etc) provide API to third-party developer to call. are those APIs the web services that the sites provide?
- Are those web sites themselves built on top of those public APIs/web services? theoretically is it possible?
- Comparing the traditionally built web site and the websites build on top of web service, pros and cons? are there any performance, scalability, etc differences?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure somebody can give you a more exact answer but reading your question and applying my self-taught knowledge:

- The simple technical definition of Web Services according to W3C:

  A Web service is a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network.

  http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-ws-gloss-20040211/

  I like to think of web services as the interactive elements of a site that its customer base utilizes.  For example, Twitter's web services include: tweeting, messages, hashtags, etc.  **Web services are what users get to DO or DATA passed back and forth.**
- A public web API provides means for developers to utilize the web services on their own site.  For example, Twitter's API allows example.com site to utilize tweeting, messaging, hashtags, etc from within their own domain.  **An API is how developers get external access to web services to make apps using those services.**
- I have no idea about this question.  I wouldn't do that.  I would use the methods the public API exposes access to.  But, I've never written my own API, let alone on the scale of Twitter or foursquare.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, maybe you need some more info about what an API is: please take a look at the [Wikipedia api page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

To answer to you questions (these are only general thoughts and not best practices):

1. An API, in this case, is a way that a developer uses to access a webservice, and it's *not* the service itself.
2. The websites you mention are not using their own APIs, as these APIs are meant for remote users (clients), and offer limited data sets, while the websites need maximum performance, access to the full database, and (almost) always use server-side code. The websites you mentioned, probably use other, server-side, high-performance APIs.
3. See the previous point: although it depends highly on which APIs you use, what you call "traditionally built websites" (that is, web applications using server-side APIs) can afford higher performance than websites totally built on top of remote APIs, because they do not depend on the bottleneck of the network connection (because, again usually, the web server and the database server either run on the same machine, or communicate faster than the client's browser and the server).
   The reason that would make most people choose to develop a webapp the traditional way is that free APIs provide limited functionality (e.g. Google custom Search, limited to 100 reults).

Comment: For 2. I guess I mean the client side/front end UI of a website. Except the layout etc, the content of the client side and the activities started from the client side and their responses could all be taken care by the APIs (public + private) that the server/web service side provide, can we say that?